# Why does Laravel 8 migration's file fails SQL query which works in SQL client?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

An update like this running from SQL client such as SQLPlus works fine:

```
alter table `questions` add constraint `questions_question_display_format_id_foreign` foreign key (`question_display_format_id`) references `question_display_formats` (`id`);
```

However while the migration is running from Laravel during deployment, the following error has been observed:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '0  
  000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'updated_at' at row 6446 (SQL: alter table `  
  questions` add constraint `questions_question_display_format_id_foreign` fo  
  reign key (`question_display_format_id`) references `question_display_forma  
  ts` (`id`))
```

I would like to understand the cause, and how to avoid such as surprise when doing a deployment.
This example works after mass updating entries to not have `created_at` and `updated_at` columns with zeroes in them - then it worked.

Comment: What unclear is in error message you posted?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I thought I was clear about this - I ran the same update table command that it failed to execute in SQL client, and it ran without errors! Why do I have to update those extra columns for Laravel to run the migrations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quicker solution is to disable `"strict"` mode on your database connection.

Strict mode controls how MySQL handles invalid or missing values in data-change statements such as `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.

you can do this by opening your config/database.php file, and make sure your database connection shows `'strict' => false`.

But, The ideal solution would be to fix all the data in the database. That is, go through your database and update your datetime/timestamp fields so that they are nullable, and convert their data from `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` to `NULL`. You can also do this by modifying your migrations.

Comment: Thank you! interesting, is there a way to do this only for the migrations instead of enabling for the entire application?

Comment: Preferably without doing like `config()->set('database.connections.mysql.strict', false);` specifically on every migration file (and actually hoping no one on the team ever forgets when schema is changed...)